# Create a drawable from image asset in a flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I am building a flutter plugin, So it wraps a native android package. This package has a class that accepts a drawable identifier. So it looks like this:

```
Builder(R.drawable.logo)
```

I would like users of my package to use their own custom images, so I would allow them to specify the files from their flutter asset folder then access it from the android code. I am able to access to image by doing this:

```
val loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
val key = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset(logoPath)

this.context.assets.open(key)
```

I am able to get an input stream of the image, however how do I make it such that I am able to pass a drawable identifier to this `Builder` as it has no overloads and only accepts a drawable identifier which is of type `int`